# Integrating existing Umbraco website design in ublogsy blogs

Tags: umbraco, blogs

I'm developing a site in umbraco, and integrating uBlogsy (blog) in it.
But the problem is, uBlogsy offers its own look n feel. However i want to have my existing website design in Blogging part as well.

here is the link for the same :

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/ublogsy

I've done that manually. but its a time taking process.

Does any one knows, how can i do that? is there any automation available for the same?

Or if there exists any better blog than uBlogsy offering same feature and functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

uBlogsy is the de-facto blog package for umbraco so i'd be surprised if you find anything better (the community is encouraged to build upon the best instead of spin up many sub-par competitors, but i digress).

> I've done that manually. but its a time taking process.

^^This sounds like you have modified the cshtml markup and css from the package. This is indeed the way to go. 
There isn't really any plug-in theming that i'm aware of and it sounds like this is what you're looking for, right?

I've used uBlogsy many times on past projects and usually don't keep anthonys files for template views but rather start with fresh markup to match my wire-comps. Since his files are included - they make a great example for how-to access the data.

Sorry it's probably not what you're looking to hear. But i think it ultimately gives greater control and better result to get hands-on.